# XSLT Sheet Grabbing wrong information

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to convert a XML file to a CSV file.  My XSLT sheet is pulling the `-->` in front of certain numbers.  This is causing `--&gt;` to be displayed on my CSV.  How do I stop this from happening?  I am trying to grab the Monetary Amount in the below XML.

XSLT Sheet

```
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$tran/BPR/BPR02"/>
<xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
```

XML

```
-<BPR> 
<!--Transaction Handling Code-->
-<BPR01>I
<!--Remittance Information Only-->
</BPR01> 
<!--Monetary Amount-->
<BPR02>22615.08</BPR02> 
<!--Credit/Debit Flag Code-->
-<BPR03>C
<!--Credit-->
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Use**: `<xsl:output method="text"/>`

Here is how your fragment-code could look like in a transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/BPR/BPR02"/>
    <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document -- corrected to be well-formed:**

```
<BPR>
    <!--Transaction Handling Code-->
    <BPR01>I
        <!--Remittance Information Only-->
    </BPR01>
    <!--Monetary Amount-->
    <BPR02>22615.08</BPR02>
    <!--Credit/Debit Flag Code-->
    <BPR03>C</BPR03>
    <!--Credit-->
</BPR>
```

**the result doesn't contain unwanted characters:**

```
"22615.08",
```